# sign in page doesn't work swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a sign in page using this  tutorial:

https://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2015/07/ios-login-signup-screen-tutorial-swift-2-xcode-7-ios-9-json/

Made changes on my need tested with web service on tutorial working fine but wen I try my web service it doesn't login but in xcode log I have data that I want. I want to show them in other page that uses a different class.

Login view controller codes:

```
do {
            let post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

            NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://www.k-pay.ir/home/loginpost")!

            let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

            let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

            let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = postData
            request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


            var reponseError: NSError?
            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData?
            do {
                urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                reponseError = error
                urlData = nil
            }

            if ( urlData != nil ) {
                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

                NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                {
                    let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

                    //var error: NSError?

                    let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary



                    let buildingid: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("buildingid") as! NSString
                    let buildingname: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("buildingname") as! NSString
                    let unitOwnerName: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("unitOwnerName") as! NSString
                    let unitMostajerName: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("unitMostajerName") as! NSString
                    let SakenMoteqayyer: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("SakenMoteqayyer") as! NSString
                    let SakenSabet: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("SakenSabet") as! NSString
                    let BedehiMalek = (jsonData["BedehiMalek"] as? NSString) ?? 0
                    let Tedad: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("Tedad") as! NSString
                    let Metragh: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("Metragh") as! NSString
                    let unitId: NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("unitId") as! NSString
```

And Code I wrote in home view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    }else {

        Tedad.text = "\(Tedad)"
        Metragh.text = "\(Metragh)"
        buildingid.text = "\(buildingid)"
        buildingname.text = "\(buildingname)"
        unitId.text = "\(unitId)"
        unitMostajerName.text = "\(unitMostajerName)"
        unitOwnerName.text = "\(unitOwnerName)"
        SakenMoteqayyer.text = "\(SakenMoteqayyer)"
        SakenSabet.text = "\(SakenSabet)"
        BedehiMalek.text = "\(BedehiMalek)"

    }

}
```

}
I've connected some labels in my home view controller.

Why sign in doesn't work and how can I place data in an other class?

------UPDATE------
Added this code signs in well but not showing datas in labels well:

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    prefs.setObject(buildingid, forKey: "buildingid")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(buildingname, forKey: "buildingname")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(unitOwnerName, forKey: "unitOwnerName")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(unitMostajerName, forKey: "unitMostajerName")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(SakenMoteqayyer, forKey: "SakenMoteqayyer")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(SakenSabet, forKey: "SakenSabet")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(BedehiMalek, forKey: "BedehiMalek")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(Tedad, forKey: "Tedad")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(Metragh, forKey: "Metragh")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()

                    prefs.setObject(unitId, forKey: "unitId")
                    prefs.setInteger(1, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
                    prefs.synchronize()


                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Labels are shown like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOQJx.png)

Comment: This is an incredibly diffucult question to answer given the information you've provided. Please show the code that you are working with so we can actually point out where you are going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by ["doesn't work"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)?

Comment: I run my app, enter username and password then click login button. But no signing in. it shows loading symbol but after it finishes, nothing happens. @nhgrif

Comment: All of these details are useless in comments and must be part of the question proper.  You need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36120688/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem by replacing code below in my home view controller.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
    if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    }else {
        self.Tedad.text = prefs.valueForKey("Tedad") as? String
        self.Metragh.text = prefs.valueForKey("Metragh") as? String
        self.buildingid.text = prefs.valueForKey("buildingid") as? String
        self.buildingname.text = prefs.valueForKey("buildingname") as? String
        self.unitId.text = prefs.valueForKey("unitId") as? String
        self.unitMostajerName.text = prefs.valueForKey("unitMostajerName") as? String
        self.BedehiMalek.text = prefs.valueForKey("BedehiMalek") as? String
        self.unitOwnerName.text = prefs.valueForKey("unitOwnerName") as? String
        self.SakenMoteqayyer.text = prefs.valueForKey("SakenMoteqayyer") as? String
        self.SakenSabet.text = prefs.valueForKey("SakenSabet") as? String
    }

}
```